# Issue On Animating Div on Adding and Removing Animate Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Can you please take a look at <kbd>[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/bt0azL3x/1/)</kbd>  and let me know why I am not able to add the Animation to second click (Doesn't Matter Add or Update)in to the div

I am using Animate.css plugin and the codes work fine for each one at first but after adding the removeClass() both of animation not functioning

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li>Model: Economics <span id="data"> </span></li>
</ol>
<button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
<button id="update" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
         $('#data').html('Just Been Added');
         $('#data').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
         $('#data').removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    });
    $("#update").on("click", function () {
         $('#data').html('Just Been Updated');
         $('#data').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
         $('#data').removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/bt0azL3x/2/, the reason was you removed and added the class at the same time, since the animation lasts 1sec I  set a timeout to remove it at that interval. If you change the speed of the animation you'll have to do the same for the timeout in js.

Comment: Thanks Ervald but how come I cant get the pvrivous animation classes as " animated bounceInLeft" ?

Comment: Since the element is animated and the class `animated` is required by default you don't have to re-add it.

Comment: Or you can do it in a faster/simpler way. http://jsfiddle.net/bt0azL3x/4/ by adding the `span` element each time.